# Google cloud charging me a lot to send a few emails

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I have a static Angular site from which I send emails. I set up a node/express email server which simply sends the emails using Gmail. This server is hosted on Google App Engine. I can see that it has sent 82 emails so far - only a few lines long - over two months. I have been billed over €200 for this by App Engine. How is this possible?

I have sent a support request but no response so far. I am just wondering if it could be something I have done.

Comment: It´s not likely that the length of the emails will impact the cost for using the service. There should be a history graph in the app engine settings where you can se the resource consumption for the app engine profile. If your app has been used for some sort of external shenanigans the resources might have been maxed out for some time, impacting the costs. Or (less likely,) the calculations over att Google misfired for your account.

Comment: How can you be sure it's the emails you are being charged for? Have you looked into the bill provided by Google? Does it specifically say you're being charged €200 for the emails sent? Could you post a screenshot of the bill (first hiding all sensitive information)?

Comment: Okay it doesn't specify I am being charged for the emails themselves but the server has charges of $0.072 per hour. It has only been online since August 15th, which is 864 hours. If my math is correct that equals roughly $62. I have been charged far more.

Comment: @Finnjon depending on load and your application - you might have had more than one instance running at the same time which would add hours pretty quickly. You might want to show your bill (first hiding any sensitive information) to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lower you'r costs, GCP is suggesting using sendgrid API to send emails. For GCP Projects there is 12k emails free quota/month. You can add sendgrid API, create account and hook up to your project by going into google cloud console -> cloud launcher and typing sendgrid.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up for the google cloud free service they bill you by the instance. However, they give you no control over how many instances are used at any given time. I am/was being billed for two instances on one of my projects despite the fact that it has received a total of 83 requests in the five weeks since it was deployed.

I am waiting for Google to try to explain this to me.